# pyplot blend mode for overlapping lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to blend pyplot lines where they overlap?

Right now I'm using alpha with two colors that add up nicely to a different enough color. I don't really like though that they also blend with the white background, I'd like full colors and something like "add" or "multiply" blend mode where they overlap...

Any idea?

Comment: If playing with alpha values isn't getting you what you want, I'd suggest calculating the intersection and plotting that as a third line over top.

Comment: Good point, not really applicable to my current problem though, because they overlap almost completely. So I'd like something like a yellow patch in the legend for line1, a blue patch for line2, but you only see a single green line because they overlap. Maybe I could hack something hardcoding legend patch colors...

Comment: I'd use dashes: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html

Comment: @mauve thank you, dashes actually solve my problem, I can plot one solid line and one dashed with another color and the result shows pretty well how they overlap. Will leave the question open anyway, blend modes could still be useful.